# Was Buddha a Hindu?

Tags: history, other-religions, buddhism, kshatriya

I was wondering where to post such a question. I chose Hinduism because it is the most liberal religion.

My question is: Was Buddha a Hindu? Was he a Kshatriya?

Comment: As per Brihaspati Agama and Brhan Naradiya Purana, **Hindu** was a geographical term (from **Hi**malya to Si**ndu**) rather a religion name when Buddha was born...so everyone who was born in Hindusthan (area from Himalaya to Sindu (Indian Ocean)) was a Hindu only...

Comment: "I chose Hinduism because it is the most liberal religion." But we are Hinduism _site_. We also have scope just like any other SE site. Also only ask one question per post. You are asking two.

Comment: As per tradition Buddha was born in Solar dynasty. @YDS But some scriptures say a Hindu is the one who accept Vedas. But Buddhism rejects Vedas as per my knowledge.

Comment: @NarayanaSharma which scripture says so?..it might be Arya or some other term but I don't think it is hindu...our dharma was known as Santana Dharma and not Hindu..Hindu was geographical term... it's only invaders who changed geographical term to religion name..and these invaders changed it much after than Buddha...